# Creating a table as a sql script

Tags: mysql

I need to create a table with a file or anything, everything needs to be done as a sql script.

Can someone help me create a table without a csv file,

The name of the table is "videos"

The rows will be:

unique id 
title 
minutes 
URL

Comment: You should be more specific and maybe provide examples of your solutions so others could help you.

Answer (score 1):

When creating table to database via script you need to create a file where you will define structure of table with **DDL** (Data definition language).

**For example**
Create file `table.sql`. Open file and use [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) statement for table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE videos(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    minutes INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

Afterwards you can run this script in many different ways. For example in Linux based operating systems you can run script with command **mysql** in form `mysql -u user -p database_name < table.sql`, where user is your **username** and **database_name** is name of database for which you want to create table.

Comment: thank you so much! Now I need to add the information to the table how would I do that ?  Instructions:  On the newly created schema, create one table to keep track of the videos. This table should include a unique ID, the title of the video, the length in minutes, and the URL. Populate the table with at least three related videos from YouTube, the Microsoft Power BI site, or other publicly available resources.

Comment: I assume you are learning basics of database systems. Is it for your study or work ? I recommend you to find some online course or tutorial and go step by step to learn it and understand it. For example one good online course is [W3Schools SQL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). It offers minimum theory to understand SQL language and also it lets you execute queries directly from web on their database so you can practice what you have learned.